# Possible ways of exploiting PHP register_globals

Tags: web-application, php, webserver

I have a PHP script that executes a bunch of commands to verify that a user is logged.

```
if (( isset ($password) && $password!="" && auth($password,$hidden_password)==1) || (is_array($_SESSION) && $_SESSION["logged"]==1 ) ){
    $aff=display("you're logged in);
} else {
    $aff=display("you're not logged in");
}
```

If `register_globals` is set to 1 in my `php.ini`, and I want to *inject* something into the URL to get authentified every time, whichever the password is, what can I do?

I already tried:

- `site.com/page.php?password=pass&logged=1`
- `site.com/page.php?password=pass&_SESSION["logged"]=array("1")`
- `site.com/page.php?password=pass&hidden_password=pass` ==> returns "*you're not logged in*" but the thing is that I don't want to overwrite the Hidden_Password (I need it!)
- I tried to play also with cookies, and other http headers, but with no results

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this specific vulnerability you need to call `start_session()`  before using a session variable. This way,  PHP will initiate `$_SESSION` and overwrite the injected values.  For the value`$hidden_password`,  this needs to initialized somewhere in the application and therefore cannot be controlled.

In general `register_globals` should be disabled!  It causes other security problems and will be removed from the language